# Windows changed my wallpaper

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

This is not a problem, merely perplexing. I simply do not understand how it could happen and wondered if anyone here could suggest what Windows 10 is up to. I have five computers all running Windows 10 1903. (And one Linux computer!) I am neither a naive Windows user nor a naive network user, but this has be flummoxed.

I connected remotely (RDP) from my personal account on my regular computer to my media computer. The media computer has only one user, my administrative account. When I logged off the media computer, my wallpaper changed to that of my daughter's user account on a third computer on my home network.

I have read some other answers and here is how my situation differs.

No one logs in with Microsoft accounts. Individual sync has its default settings, which syncs everything. However, I set up every user on every computer as a local user account. Every user on my local network logs in only to their local account. I have Microsoft OneDrive installed on every computer, but it does not execute when Windows starts and no one logs in to it.

I am an Office 365 subscription user and therefore my five computers all log in to the same Office 365 account for licensing purposes. I worked on a Word document just before I used RDC and my daughter had a Word document open on her computer. I know that Word tries very hard to force all documents to OneDrive via Office 365 even if OneDrive is not running.

Why and how did Windows 10 sync the wallpaper between two different user accounts on two different computers. I am baffled. Suggestions?

And as of the next day, three different accounts on three different computers.

Comment: Ask your daughter why she is playing pranks on her Dad.

Comment: She only changed the wallpaper on her account on one computer. I know because she does not know the passwords to any accounts but her own. I opened my laptop this morning (fourth computer) with the local admin account and its wallpaper changed, too. Interestingly, on her computer, the wallpaper is not changed for  either my personal account or the admin account. So bizarre.